# Loop through dynamic columns

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have this df

```
require(data.table)

df <- data.table(a = 1:2
                 , b = 3:4
                 , c = 5:6
                 ); df

   a b c
1: 1 3 5
2: 2 4 6
```

and I wanted to fetch 2 columns at a time e.g. c('a', 'b') then c('a', 'c'). I tried:

```
x <- c('b', 'c')

for (i in x)
{
  print( df[, c('a', i)]  )
}
```

instead of returning a data table with the specified columns it only returned the vector of the specified column names:

```
[1] "a" "b"
[1] "a" "c"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) with** Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end add `with=FALSE`

```
for (i in x) {
  print( df[, c('a', i), with = FALSE]  )
}
```

giving:

```
   a b
1: 1 3
2: 2 4
   a c
1: 1 5
2: 2 6
```

**2) dot dot** This would also work and gives the same result.

```
for (i in x) {
  cn <- c('a', i)
  print( df[, ..cn]  )
}
```

**3) .SD**  We can use `.SD` with `.SDcols` like this:

```
for (i in x) {
  print( df[, .SD, .SDcols = c("a", i)]  )
}
```

**4) subset** We could use the subset function.  It has a data.table method.

```
for (i in x) {
  print( subset(df, select = c('a', i)) )
}
```

**5) data.frame** Also if you use a data frame rather than a data.table then it would work without any of the above.

```
DF <- as.data.frame(df)
for (i in x) {
  print( DF[, c('a', i)]  )
}
```

giving:

```
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
  a c
1 1 5
2 2 6
```

### Note

The question was missing the library statement and definition of `x` so we used the following.

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(a = 1:2
                 , b = 3:4
                 , c = 5:6
                 ); df

x <- c("b", "c")
```

Comment: To make it slightly more robust, I would adapt it to this:
for (i in 2:length(names(df))) {
  print(df[, c(1, i), with = F])
}

Comment: I was aware of the `..` method but wondered if there was a method that did not necessitate creating another vector. `with = F` was what I was after
Thank you !

Comment: Added .SD alternative.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg
Yes, this works too. Though is more situation specific. e.g. column indexing by number

Comment: @G.Grothendieck
Very true. I too knew of `.SD` but had only used in context of `apply`. Need to think outside the box more